# How to plot matrix with rgb image?

Tags: matrix, colors, gnuplot, rgb, palette

I want to plot `m*n` matrix, each element of which is an `rgb` triple, like in the following *gnuplot* code snippet (rgb matrix of `3*3`):

```
$cross << EODcross
255 0 0  0 0 0  255 0 0
0   0 0  0 0 0    0 0 0
255 0 0  0 0 0  255 0 0
EODcross
```

Black cross on red background. I can change delimiters between columns and color components, if needed.

Can I achieve the desired avoiding `set palette rgbformulae i,j,k` and directly using `$cross` data? Something like:

```
plot '$cross' matrix with image rgb
```

If not, I can pass 24bit-wide integers (of course, in textual representation, i.e. precalculated and converted to text `r + 256 * (g + 256 * b)` or `b + 256 * (g + 256 * r)` value). How should `i,j,k` triple looks like to correctly map `rgb` value represented in mentioned form to palette color space?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rgbimage` plotting style expects five columns, the last three give red, blue and green values in the range [0:255]. So you can use any 24-bit integer representation of the colors, because you must extract the color channels yourself when plotting:

```
$data <<EOD
0xff   0 0xff00
0      0 0
0xffff 0 0xff00ff
EOD
r(x) = int(x) >> 16
g(x) = (int(x) >> 8) & 0xff
b(x) = int(x) & 0xff
plot $data matrix using 1:2:(r($3)):(g($3)):(b($3)) with rgbimage
```

[image]

Comment: What means first two?

Comment: 1 and 2 are x and y coordinates. When using `matrix`, gnuplot internally generates three columns: first is the matrix column, second is matrix row and the third contains the actual matrix data values

Answer (score 2):

It seems that ascii matrix data and rgbimage do not fit together.

If you are free to format your input data, then put each column of the image into a single block, separating the blocks by two blank lines like this:

```
$cross << EODcross
255 0 0  
  0 0 0
255 0 0


0 0 0    
0 0 0    
0 0 0


255 0 0  
  0 0 0
255 0 0
EODcross
```

Then plot the cross like this:

```
plot $cross using -2:0:1:2:3 with rgbimage
```

The numbers -2 and 0 in the `using` section correspond to the pseudo columns "block index" and "line within a block", respectively. They are used as x and y values. The `plot with rgbimage` style requires `x,y,r,g,b` data.

This is the result:

[image: black cross]