# Assigning transparency to certain elements of a matrix in pm3d map

Tags: plot, gnuplot

There are two data files and I need to overlap their color maps using pm3d map. I need to assign transparency to the lowest values, so that I can actually overlap two plots.

First data file `data1.dat` contains:

```
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   30  1
1   45  1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
```

Second data file `data2.dat` is :

```
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   1   1
1   1   1   80  1
1   1   1   20  1
```

Here is what I tried with gnuplot file :

```
set terminal png
set output 'data_plot.png'
set pm3d map

set multiplot

stats "data1.dat" matrix name "A"
show variables A_
stats "data2.dat" matrix name "B"
show variables B_

splot for[i=0:4] 'data1.dat' matrix using (column(i)==A_min ? NaN :column(i)/A_max), for[i=0:4] 'data2.dat' matrix using (column(i)==B_min ? NaN :column(i)/B_max)
```

When I put the condition `column(i)==A_min`, it is checking the column number (obviously) to be A_min; is there a way to check the value of the elements instead (access the element)?
I need to assign all the elements with value "1" as transparent.

Answer (score 1):

I could not get `pm3d` to work, probably because of the NaN values. Would it be an option to use `rgbalpha` instead   (`help rgbalpha`)?

```
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'data_plot.png'

stats "data1.dat" matrix name "A"
show variables A_
stats "data2.dat" matrix name "B"
show variables B_

set nokey

r(x) = 255*sqrt(x)                  # rgbformulae 7
g(x) = 255*x**3                     # rgbformulae 5
b(x) = 255*(0.5+0.5*sin(2.0*pi*x))  # rgbformulae 15
a(x) = (x==1) ? 0 : 255             # fully transparent or opaque

plot 'data1.dat' matrix using 1:2:(r($3/A_max)):(g($3/A_max)):(b($3/A_max)):(a($3)) with rgbalpha ,\
     'data2.dat' matrix using 1:2:(r($3/B_max)):(g($3/B_max)):(b($3/B_max)):(a($3)) with rgbalpha
```

The command `plot with rgbalpha` expects 6 columns: x,y,r,g,b,alpha. This means that we need the coordinates and that   we have to map the matrix values to color values. We take some ideas from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040430/7010554). Citing a [comment from Christoph](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42040430/7010554):

> When using matrix, gnuplot internally generates three columns: first is the matrix column, second is matrix row and   the third contains the actual matrix data values.

For the calculation of the colors the default mapping is used (after reading `help rgbformulae`, `show palette rgbformulae`). The color values r, g, and b are expected to be between 0 and 255. The matrix values are mapped such that the highest value in each file will be shown in yellow. The transparency function a(x) returns 0 (fully transparent) for argument 1, else it returns 255 (opaque).

This is the result:

[image: two matrices with some transparency]

Note that the plotting style "rgbalpha" and "pm3d" treat the coordinates differently. This might need some adjustment of xrange and yrange or some shift of `using 1:2:...` like `using ($1+0.5):($2+0.5):...`, depending on your needs.